# Doit-on écrire « en détail » ou « en détails » ?

Tags: orthographe, pluriel

Quelle est l'orthographe correcte entre « en détail » et « en détails » et pourquoi ?

> Je vais vous présenter ça en détail(s).

A priori et par logique, j'aurais tendance à utiliser la version au pluriel car il y a souvent plusieurs détails mais je ne suis pas certain que la phrase serait correctement orthographiée.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Officiellement c'est l'expression figée "en détail" qu'il faut utiliser. Celle-ci a la même source que quand on parle de "vente au détail" (par opposition à la vente en gros) ; on dit ici qu'on va s'intéresser aux éléments individuels un à un et pas de manière générale.

Dans la pratique, tant de gens écrivent "en détails" (il suffit de voir les suggestions Google), que personne ne reprochera la faute.

Comment: Merci pour l'explication simple et claire.

Answer (score 5):

*[§ II.A.2 - Loc. adv. Avec détail (vieilli), en détail (usuel)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9tail)* :
En entrant dans les moindres parties, en n'omettant aucune circonstance.

> - Je vous le montre *en détail*,...
> - le plus *en détail* possible.

Au *§ II.B.1.a*, par extension (mais sans l'utilisation de *en*)

> - On tend trop à surcharger les études *de détails* et de minuties aux dépens de l'esprit.
> - ...descendre aux détails, entrer dans les détails, passer sur les détails, se perdre dans les détails.

Un premier regard sur le *[Ngram "détail, détails"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en%20d%C3%A9tail%2C%20en%20d%C3%A9tails&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3)*, *en détails* renvoie à des pages de forum qui posent une question semblable à la vôtre, ou alors à des livres qui font des collations *de détails*, qui rassemblent plusieurs chapitres *de détails*, qui regroupent plusieurs études qui analysent *en détail* de nombreuses situations.

Nombre de livres utilisent *en détails* d'une manière fautive dans des locutions adverbiales.

Pour l'exemple cité dans la question , il faut en rester à ***en détail*** (locution adverbiale), sans *s*.

S'il s'agissait de dénombrer *les* détails :

> Plus une photo de macro est riche ***en détails*** (nom), plus elle est intéressante.

... on peut alors remplacer *en* par *de*, ce qui est possible lorsque *détails* est un nom, mais impossible lorsqu'il s'agit d'une locution adverbiale.

Comment: @L'aditdabenlà - La phrase est tirée d'un livre listé dans la recherche du Ngram https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22en+d%C3%A9tails%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=cr&ei=368nV7HvDMH36ATDk4jIDA (1er page en bas, sur mon écran)

Comment: @PapaPoule -- J'ai réorganisé les trois dernières phrases... en espérant qu'il n'y ait plus d’ambiguïté à cette nouvelle lecture.

Answer (score 2):

**Les deux sont possibles:**

**l'expression *en détail* utilise le singulier** = *par une énumération complète* ... = *par le détail, dans le détail, dans les moindres détails*

Comme elle existe et est fréquemment employée et comprise, autant l'utiliser.

L'amalgame vient du fait que détail signifie à la fois l'énumération, et chacune des parties.

**en + substantif au pluriel est toujours possible** :

> Je vais vous l'expliquer ...
>
> - en détails : détail par détail
> - en parties
> - en morceaux (en portions, en tranche)

Comment: Attention, on dit bien "dans les moindres détail*s*", puisque là on utilise le nom "détail" au pluriel.

Comment: @AnneAunyme , bien sûr. Corrigé.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Au détail*** = à l'unité, par petites quantités. *Vente au détail*. Toujours au singulier.
>
> ***En détail*** = avec précision, minutieusement, sans rien omettre. *Raconter les faits en détail. Examiner une question en détail*. Toujours au singulier.
>
> [ *Dictionnaires de français [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9tail/24748/difficulte) en ligne*, à détail, section
>   difficultés ]
>
> ---
>
> Les locutions adverbiales *en détail* et *au détail* ont des sens bien
>   différents, mais elles ont en commun le fait que *détail* y est
>   toujours au singulier.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (BDL), [détail](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=d%C3%A9tail&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) ]

Je n'ai remarqué ni sur le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9tail) ni sur [Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/d%C3%A9tail), ni dans la section [*questions de langue*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue) un exemple où on aurait *en* suivi de *détail* avec la marque du pluriel pour cette locution adverbiale. En fait même la vieille locution *avec détail* est au singulier. Le *ngram* présenté dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19004) illustre plus de dix singuliers pour un pluriel. C'est [*toujours*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toujours/78644?q=toujours#77718) au singulier en locution adverbiale dans le sens de *avec précision, sans rien omettre*. C'est aussi le cas avec le sens du *discours minutieux* comme dans *il a fallu qu'elle nous raconte tout par le détail.* ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9tail/24748))

---

Évidemment, on peut omettre un ou des détails, ne raconter aucun détail des moindres détails, entrer dans le détail (l'énumération), dans les détails (les éléments) etc., mais la locution adverbiale *en détail*<sup>1</sup> sans complément est reliée au *détail* comme action unique à visées multiples pourrait-on dire, d'où le singulier à mon avis. Le TLFi note aussi *en détail* en complément prépositionnel d'une locution usuelle (*on les invita à tout visiter en détail*, par exemple, *[e]n n'omettant aucun élément d'un ensemble*), encore une fois au *singulier*. Que l'exemple se rapproche davantage de la locution adverbiale (*[...]et ce nous est, dès lors, un devoir impérieux de parler d'elle le plus au long et le plus en détail possible.*) ou de celle qui est usuelle et complète la préposition (...*inviter à visiter en détail*), il s'agit du singulier *en détail*.

Finalement, le sens d'un truc comme [*riche en détails*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19004) est incompatible avec celui de l'exemple en question (*présenter ça*), le *détail* n'étant pas l'objet (ça) de la présentation mais plutôt sa manière (*complètement*) ; qui plus est, l'[expression](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=riche&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) *[riche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/riche) en* marque l'*abondance*, et *riche de*, la *quantité* : il ne s'agit pas de la locution adverbiale *en détail*, mais on a bien la préposition suivie du nom au pluriel sans erreur. On peut aussi comparer les difficultés avec [couleur(s)](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/couleur/19757/difficulte).

---

> Je vais vous présenter ça en détail. [singulier uniquement] 
>  Je vais vous présenter
>   ma recherche dans le détail. 
>  Je vais vous présenter les résultats de ma recherche sans en négliger les détails.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> L'emploi de la locution *en détail* doit aussi s'analyser à la lumière d'un domaine particulier comme la vente, entre autres, où l'on utilise aussi la préposition *en* mais de manière usuelle. On peut distinguer la *vente à détail* qui devient la *vente en détail*, ultimement *au détail* (*par petites quantités*), et donc le commerce *de détail* par opposition à *de gros*, du détail qui est pertinent ici, soit celui ayant trait aux *parties successives*, à *toutes les particularités* par opposition à *en général* ; et de là *la petite partie d'un ensemble* (un, des détails) et l'idée de *le détail* comme *action de considérer les composants d'un ensemble*, ou les circonstances d'une situation. *Ne pas faire le(de) détail de* s'y rattache, alors que *faire le détail de*, disparu, se rattachait à la *division en morceaux*. (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed. Robert ; [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/d%C3%A9tail)).</sub>